# How do I remove default behavior of "shift-enter" or add custom behavior in tiptap react

Tags: reactjs, tiptap

Implementing ordered and unordered list using tiptap react. I want functionality like when user currently in any list or any list is active in text-area of tiptap then by hit the enter key message should send with a single ordered list. The problem is when I need to add another line in same list, using shift+enter key for jumping in new line with updated number of list for example:

```
"1. currently writing  in text-area" `hitting shift-enter key` 
the expected output is 
"1. currently writing  in text-area"
"2. some other line"
```

but I got

```
"1. currently writing  in text-area"
"2. "
" " `cursor is in next line` .
```

I found out the problem is with every shift + enter hit tiptap adds 
 tag and add a simple break line in between any working node.

I tried with adding

```
const removeBlankSpace = () => {
      const abc = editor?.getHTML().replace("<br>", " ") || "";
      editor?.commands.setContent(abc);
    };
```

removing blank space or 
 tag explicitly and setting up inside editor.commands.setContent

```
const editor = useEditor({
      extensions: [
        Document.extend({
          // @ts-ignore
          addCommands() {
            return {
              setNewParagraph:
                () =>
                // @ts-ignore
                ({ commands, editor }) => {
                  const { state } = editor;
                  const { selection } = state;
                  const { $head } = selection;
                  const position = $head.after();

                  return commands.insertContentAt(
                    { from: position, to: position },
                    { type: Paragraph.name } // Note this is adding a paragraph
                  );
                },
            };
          },
          addKeyboardShortcuts() {
            return {
              Enter: () => {
                emitCustomEvent("enter-key-tiptap");
                return true;
              },
            };
          },
        }),

        StarterKit.configure({
          document: false,
          heading: {
            levels: [1, 2, 3, 4],
          },
        }),
        Strike,
        Highlight.configure({ multicolor: true }),
        Link.configure({
          openOnClick: true,
        }),
        Emoji.configure({
          emojis: [...gitHubEmojis],
          enableEmoticons: true,
          forceFallbackImages: true,
        }),
        Placeholder.configure({
          showOnlyWhenEditable: false,
          showOnlyCurrent: true,
          includeChildren: true,
          placeholder: () => "Send a message",
        }),
        Link.configure({
          openOnClick: false,
        }),
        MentionExtension,
        MentionTipTap.configure(),
      ],
      editorProps: {
        attributes: {
          class: `prose prose-sm custom-note sm:prose-sm lg:prose-lg xl:prose-2xl mx-auto focus:outline-none`,
        },
        handleKeyDown(view, event) {
          // For the purpose of detect key inside ordered and unordered list.
          if (keyPressCheck.key === "Shift" && event.key === "Enter") {
            console.log("emit new list");
            emitCustomEvent("new-line-list");
          }
          keyPressCheck.key = event.key;
          if (keyPressCheck.key !== "Shift" && event.key === "Enter") {
            emitCustomEvent("enter-for-list");
          }
        },
      },
      autofocus: "end",
      onUpdate({ editor, transaction }) {
        onChange(editor as Editor);
      },
      content: ``,
    });
    const handleEnterKeyForList = () => {
      if (editor?.can().splitListItem("listItem")) {
        console.log("enter key submit here");
        onMessageSend();
      }
    };
    // editor?.commands.setContent("<ul><li><p>jg</p></li><li><p></p></li></ul>");
    const removeBlankSpace = () => {
      console.log(
        "changes donw ------------------------------",
        editor?.getHTML()
      );
      // const abc = editor?.getHTML().replace("<br>", " ") || "";
      // console.log("abc: ", abc);
      // editor?.commands.setContent(abc);
    };

    const handleNewLineUpdate = () => {
      if (
        editor?.isActive("orderedList") ||
        (editor?.isActive("bulletList") &&
          editor.can().splitListItem("listItem"))
      ) {
        editor?.chain().focus().splitListItem("listItem").run();
        removeBlankSpace();
      }
    };
    
    useCustomEventListener("enter-key-tiptap", handleEnterKey);
    useCustomEventListener("enter-for-list", handleEnterKeyForList);
    useCustomEventListener("new-line-list", handleNewLineUpdate);
```

Comment: I dont really get you example. 
For a number list shit+enter should just add a <br> tag which just make a linebreak. 
Could you share your code of the implementation so we can see what extensions you use and try to explain your example a bit better, maybe add the html you expect and the html you get

Comment: I want Shift-Enter to add new list item editor?.chain().focus().splitListItem("listItem").run();

Rather than add new line.

Comment: Added code in question.

Comment: The <br> is added in HardBreak, a part of StarterKit, do you want to remove shift enter -> <br> completely or just for lists?

Comment: Want to remove <br> tag and in place of that tag no <p> tag should be placed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still want to keep HardBreak I would suggest to extend the HardBreak extension, that will check if you should allow hard break.

```js
import HardBreakTiptap from "@tiptap/extension-hard-break";
import { Node as ProseMirrorNode } from "prosemirror-model";
export interface HardBreakOtions {
  excludeTypes?: string[];
}
declare module "@tiptap/core" {
  interface Commands<ReturnType> {
    extendedHardBreak: {
      setHardBreak: () => ReturnType;
      setBasedOnType: () => ReturnType;
    };
  }
}
const HardBreak = HardBreakTiptap.extend<HardBreakOtions>({
  addOptions() {
    return {
      ...this.parent?.(),
      excludeTypes: [],
    };
  },
  addCommands() {
    return {
      ...this.parent?.(),
      setBasedOnType:
        () =>
        ({ commands, chain, state, editor }) => {
          const { selection } = state;
          const excludeTypes = this.options.excludeTypes;
          if (
            excludeTypes &&
            selection.$anchor.path.some((item: ProseMirrorNode | number) => {
              if (item instanceof ProseMirrorNode) {
              }
              return (
                item instanceof ProseMirrorNode &&
                excludeTypes.includes(item?.type?.name)
              );
            })
          ) {
            //
            return false;
          }

          return commands.setHardBreak();
        },
    };
  },
  addKeyboardShortcuts() {
    return {
      ...this.parent?.(),
      "Shift-Enter": () => {
        return this.editor.commands.setBasedOnType();
      },
    };
  },
});

export default HardBreak;
```

If you use StarterKit make sure to turn of hardBreak that otherwise it will cause issues

```
 StarterKit.configure({
        hardBreak: false,
      }),
```

You can then configure the custom hard break with the the types you want to block

```
 HardBreak.configure({
        excludeTypes: ["listItem"],
      })
```

Note that the extended HardBreak will not do anything if the type is excluded and you will have to add the keyboard shortcut to the extensions you want. In your case

```js
import ListItemTipTap from "@tiptap/extension-list-item";

const ListItem = ListItemTipTap.extend({
  addKeyboardShortcuts() {
    return {
      ...this.parent?.(),
      "Shift-Enter": () => {
        return this.editor.commands.splitListItem(this.name);
      },
    };
  },
});

export default ListItem;
```

Note that you will have to exclude even this from StartKit:

```
StarterKit.configure({
        hardBreak: false,
        listItem: false,
      }),
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll update as per your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found out solution just now with the reference from [here](https://github.com/ueberdosis/tiptap/issues/2302).

created a new extension and implement it inside `editor=({extensions:[ShifEnter]})`.

Instead of creating new

tag. I removed the hardBreak functionality pf tiptap.

here is the component shiftEnter: =>

```
import { Node } from "@tiptap/core";
export const ShiftEnter = Node.create({
  name: "shiftEnter",
  addCommands() {
    return {
      setNewParagraph:
        () =>
        ({ commands, editor }) => {
          const { state } = editor;
          const { selection } = state;
          const { $head } = selection;
          const position = $head.after();
          return commands.insertContentAt({ from: position, to: position });
        },
    };
  },
  addKeyboardShortcuts() {
    return {
      "Shift-Enter": () => this.editor.commands.setNewParagraph(),
    };
  },
});`
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question has two parts and I can help answering the first one.
I was able to remove the default behaviour or override the keyboard shortcut by extending the HardBreak extension.

```
import HardBreak from '@tiptap/extension-hard-break';

export const AppHardBreak = HardBreak.extend({
  addKeyboardShortcuts() {
    return {
      'Mod-Enter': () => this.editor.commands.setHardBreak(),
    };
  },
});
```

The code above just overrides all the shortcuts and adds 'Mod-Enter' back in. Alternatively, you can destructure the parent's (ie. HardBreak) shortcuts and override the one you want.

```
import HardBreak from '@tiptap/extension-hard-break';

export const AppHardBreak = HardBreak.extend({
  addKeyboardShortcuts() {
    return {
      ...this.parent?.(),
      'Shift-Enter': () => true, // basically a noop, but you can add you own commands
    };
  },
});
```

If you're using the StarterKit extension you need to disable the HardBreak extension inside StarterKit, otherwise you'll see a warning that there's an extension with the same name and the two will clash.

```
  const editor = useEditor({
    extensions: [
      StarterKit.configure({ hardBreak: false }),
      AppHardBreak,
      // ...other extensions
    ],
  });
```

To add a custom behaviour you can either create a new extension or further extend HardBreak as others have mentioned.